# How to add multiple sidemenu in ionic2 framework?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I want to add two different menu for Student login and teacher login ? Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please provide some code.

Comment: I want different menu drawer (side menu)..